# oracle SQL trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am supposed to write a trigger that updates an attriubute in one of my tables. More specific:
I have an "orders" table with the attributes "orderID, customerID, date, value" and an "order items" table with the attributes "orderID, articleID, quantity". 
"value" in orders is the combined value of an order, which means the sum of (price * quantity) of every oder item.
The trigger is now supposed to keep the attribute "value" updated whenever I update, insert or delete anything in "order items".
My trigger body for "INSERT" and "DELETE" looks like this:

```
IF INSERTING THEN
  UPDATE Orders
  SET value = value + (SELECT (:NEW.quantity* articles.price)
                           FROM articles
                           WHERE articles.articleID = :NEW.articleID)
  WHERE Orders.OrderID= :NEW.OrderID;
END IF;

IF DELETING THEN
  UPDATE Orders
  SET value = value - (SELECT (:OLD.quantity * articles.price)
                           FROM articles
                           WHERE articles.articleID = :OLD.articleID)
  WHERE Orders.OrderID= :OLD.OrderID;
END IF;
```

Now we have the UPDATING case left. Here lies my problem: when INSERTING a new order item, the value of course increases, so I can just add the new value to the old one, like I did above. Same for DELETING: I can just subtract the value of the deleted row. But for update it gets tricky: Depending on whether the UPDATE statement increases or decreases the quantity, changes the article ID meaning the price increases or decreases, or does both, the value will increase or decrease. My approach so far was using many different "IF" clauses to deal with this (IF :OLD.quantity < :NEW.quantity then ... ), but this cant be the right approach. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can replace the logic for all three with:

```
  UPDATE Orders
      SET value = value + (SELECT (coalesce(:NEW.quantity, 0) - coalesce(:OLD.quantity, 0)) * a.price
                           FROM articles a
                           WHERE a.articleID = :NEW.articleID
                          )
      WHERE Orders.OrderID= :NEW.OrderID;
```

Do note that you are assuming that the price hasn't been updated.  It might be better to recalculate the entire order price, if this this is a possibility.

Comment: If i do this it says "SQL Statement ignored " for the row "UPDATE ORDERS" and for the row below that it says " KEYWORD FROM not found where expected"

Answer (score 0):

Right idea is to calculate (new - old) difference. Something like this:

```
if inserting or deleting or updating then 

  if :NEW.quantity = :OLD.quantity and :NEW.article_id = :OLD.article_id then

    null;

  else

    update orders set
      value = value + 
        coalesce((
          SELECT (:NEW.quantity * articles.price) 
          FROM articles         
          WHERE articles.articleID = :NEW.articleID), 0) -
        coalesce((
          SELECT (:OLD.quantity * articles.price) 
          FROM articles         
          WHERE articles.articleID = :OLD.articleID), 0)
    where order_id = coalesce(:NEW.order_id, :OLD.order_id);

  end if;
end if;
```

Comment: this looks good, thank you. But what if I want to change the item rather than change the quantity?

Comment: Nevermind. It works, I didn't read properly. Thank you very much!